# Expected '}' and saw '(end)'

Tags: javascript

I have uploaded my script to `http://zachucks.com/jsProblem.txt`

I have put this code into `JSLint`, and the only real error that I cannot seem to fix is it says `Expected '}'`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit, this part of the code seems to be the issue:

```js
function PumpkinGunBtn2(){
var currCash=parseInt(document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML);
if (currCash >= "7500"){
document.game.pumpkin1.disabled = false;
document.game.pumpkin2.disabled = true;
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML += '-7500';
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML);
}
else {

}
}
```

Comment: Add the code here, don't show just URL

Comment: That's *way* too much code to look through. There should be some place noted where this is (perhaps in the console if it's a syntax problem). Also please post the relevant part of the code on the site, not through a link that may be gone in the future.

Comment: There is something called whitespaces. The author of the original part of the script has used them wisely.

Comment: Sorry for posting the link, the issue is with the entire code, because the last function has no problems, so it was pointless posting a good and working function, since there is no problems with it

Comment: and I have wrote the entire script myself, I just added in the last part from an older idea that was part of the makeup of the whole script, you can see a complete version at http://zachucks.com/projects/G23/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked through the code on my browser and you are missing a closing bracket for the `adShopSelect()` function (note I've added indentation to your code to make this easier to see):

```
function adShopSelect(){
    ...
    else if (selection == "spacebase") {
        if (currCash >= "300000"){
            ...
        }
        else {

        }
    } // <-- This is the close for else if, you never closed adShopSelect()
//==================================================================================================
//End scripts for ammo and dmg mult shops
//==================================================================================================
```

You just need to add that missing bracket:

```
function adShopSelect(){
    ...
    else if (selection == "spacebase") {
        ...
    } 
} // <-- Added Bracket
```

*Note* This is why code indentation is important, it will be much easier to catch things like this. Also many text editors have bracket selections (*meaning that if you click a bracket it will show where it's matched at, chromes browser for inspection haves this and will underline the matches*), some in fact will catch missing brackets and color them.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! This was the problem, I would have spent weeks trying to catch that, you saved me alot of time, thankyou!